# Moving the pieces in accordance to chess rules when king is under check

Tags: python, chess

This function is used to validate the input and to ensure that the moves are legal. I have tried to prevent the pieces from making any moves that do not help the king when he is under check, but my main issue in here is that the pieces can make any move even if the king is under check. I think that the problem might be within the last 27 lines but here is my full code if you'd like to see it: https://pastebin.com/wQx9pHNE. Thank you so much for your time!

```
def good_baton(self, turn):
    check_white, check_black = False, False
    while True:
        coords = input('Please enter the piece\'s starting position and its ending position in the following syntax: D2 D4. ')
        result = self.syntax_validation(coords)
        # print(result)
        if result:
            starting_coords, ending_coords = result
        else:
            print('Invalid syntax')
            continue
        result = self.coordinates_validation(starting_coords, ending_coords)
        print('coordinates_validation result = ', result)
        if result:
            piece, starting_coords, ending_coords = result
        else:
            print('Invalid input')
            continue
        if piece.side != turn:
            print('This isn\'t your turn')
            continue
        if not isinstance(piece, Knight):
            result = piece.move_validation(self, ending_coords)
        else:
            result = piece.move_validation(ending_coords)
    
        if not result:
            print('Incorrect move')
            continue
        if result != 'really true':
            result = self.moving_pieces(ending_coords, piece)
        if not result:
            print('Invalid move')
            continue
        is_check = self.white_king.check_baton(self)
        if any(is_check):
            print('check')
            check_white = True
        else:
            check_white = False
        is_check = self.black_king.check_baton(self)
        if any(is_check):
            print('check')
            check_black = True
        else:
            check_black = False
        
        if check_white == True and turn == 'white':
            print('Invalid move, please prioritize the safety of your king to win')
            self.moving_pieces(starting_coords, piece)
            print(piece.initial_coords)
            continue
        if check_black == True and turn == 'black':
            print('Invalid move, please prioritize the safety of your king to win')
            self.moving_pieces(starting_coords, piece)
            print(piece.initial_coords)
            continue
        print('Valid input')
        piece.initial_coords = ending_coords
        self.display()
        break
```

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ . There is already a lot of code here, but the problem could very easily be in one of the many helper functions you're calling that you haven't showed us. It also isn't clear how you know that you "have mistakes in that section".

Comment: I did think about including the other functions in here, but I decided to send a pastebin link instead because adding them in here would make the code at least 250 lines long. I'll try to fix my question and improve it though. Please give me a second

Comment: Please first at least try on your own to *locate* the problem.

Comment: I just fixed it. I've been stuck on this problem for literally two days and I'm finally done. Thank you so much for your time.